# A Docker container silently killed by Travis CI

Tags: docker, github, travis-ci

I have a Docker image that has a few custom libraries compiled and installed for automating tests.
It has "/bin/bash" as its ENTRYPOINT, so a container created by `docker run` does not immediately exit.

However, when I run it on Travis CI, it dies after a few seconds:

```
# .travis.yml
... (omit language, os, etc)

install:
  - docker pull <dockerhub link>
  - docker run -td <dockerhub addr>
  - docker ps
  - sleep 15
  - docker ps
```

The first `docker ps` shows that the created container is up for a few seconds.
However, the second `docker ps` shows nothing; during the 15 seconds, something happened to the container.

When the commands are run on my local computer, I can observe that it is kept alive.

Is it because Travis CI kills certain docker containers? If it is true, what should I do to make it keep alive?

Comment: It might be that the container dies itself for a some reason related to the environment (the command exists). Have you tried to see inside the container logs on Travis?

Comment: When you `docker run` the container, what should it actually be doing?  Can you include the image's `Dockerfile` in the question?  (An interactive shell would be hard to work with in an automated CI environment, and a container running some artificial command "to keep the container alive" isn't really doing anything useful.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that I was running an image that was built from arm64 machine whereas my Travis CI was using AMD64. :/

For anyone who saw this, please double check your architecture. :P